# How d0 i get the number of attachments in the post

Tags: functions, attachments

Is there a function that allows me to get the number of photo's attached to a post and that also grabs the url of the first attachment to go to the attachment page for each post?

Here is an example of what i want to accomplish, that i did in photoshop

[image]

Do you see the number sixteen next to the thumbnails, thats what i want to accomplish, a code that allows the users to know how many photo's are attached to the current post they are reading and also have the number work as a link.

I want the link to grab the first photo attachment url.

My attachment are set up like this

> /year-month-day/post-title/attachment

Is this even possible?

Comment: Just a quick question, assuming that you got this to work and your Permalinks were variables based on an Image count. Wouldn't it be safe to assume your Permalinks would break when /year-month-day/post-title/16 turned to /year-month-day/post-title/17 or even /year-month-day/post-title/15? Maybe I am interpreting your question wrong.

Comment: please take a closer look, because i have explained in the simplest way possible lol, use the image as reference too........ where it has the number "16" that's suppose to be the number of attachments attached to that post, the number should also link to the first attachment in the gallery of that post

Comment: I just realized that this may be more complicated than i thought and it may need javascript for this function

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to do the work :

```
global $post;
$page_id = $post->ID;
$all_attachments = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment','post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_parent' => $page_id, 'post_status'=>'published',  'numberposts' => -1 ) );

$no_of_photos = count($all_attachments); // Gets the number of photo's attached in $no_of_photos variable
$first_img_URL = get_permalink($all_attachments[0]->ID); // Gets the URL of first attachment in  $first_img_URL variable
```

In the above code just replace the $page_id to the id of page/post to which the photos are attached.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question

Comment: I rephrased the question i hope that helps